# Antecedent ActiveCell.Address

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at vba and I have a rather simple issue. I want to obtain the address of the last active cell there was. For example, if I was at A5 and moved to B6, is there a command to obtain the address A5?

Any type of tip or suggestion is highly appreciated!

I've tried ActiveCell.Previous but that provides the address of the cell on the left of the active cell. Offsets are no use for me since the address A5 is unknown until the user changes something inside a grid of cells.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way would be to use Excel's events. You could have a look at the `SelectionChange` event, which would enable you to store the previous selection at module-level and then retrieve that value on subsequent firings of the event.

In the example below I've used the code-behind of the Workbook object, as it enables you to register selections on any sheet, but you could do the same on just one Worksheet.

If you're only interested in certain cells, then look at the `Intersect` function to refine the routine.

```
Option Explicit

Private pPreviousWorksheet As Worksheet
Private pPreviousSelection As Range

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    'Check SH object is a worksheet.
    If TypeOf Sh Is Worksheet Then

        'Check we have instances of previous objects.
        If Not pPreviousWorksheet Is Nothing And Not pPreviousSelection Is Nothing Then

            'Process code here...
            MsgBox "Previous was " & _
                pPreviousWorksheet.Name & "!" & _
                pPreviousSelection.Address(False, False)

        End If

        'Re-set the previous objects.
        Set pPreviousWorksheet = Sh
        Set pPreviousSelection = Target

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could skip the global for the sheet, since `pPreviousSelection.Parent` would give you that.